# JAVA: Why does this for-loop print out the array columns and not rows?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to understand this array. I don't understand why the system prints out column 0 instead of row 0.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] wps = {{0,1,2},{3,4,5},{6,7,8},{0,3,6},{1,4,7},{2,5,8},{0,4,8},{2,4,6}};

        for(int[] wp : wps){
              System.out.println(wp[0]);
            //System.out.println(wp[1]);
            //System.out.println(wp[2]);

        }
    }
```

output:

```
0
3
6
0
1
2
0
2
```

My assumption is that

```
for(int[] wp : wps)
```

is taking the columns but I thought that 2D arrays are structured

> int [row][column]

If someone can explain this to me that would be awesome.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're printing the first element in each of the subarrays: `{{**0**,1,2}, {**3**,4,5}, {**6**,7,8}, ...`.

Comment: 2D arrays are structured however you structure them. They're not intrinsically row-first or column-first. Only your usage or interpretation.

Comment: Because that is what you are asking it to do. `wp` is the row and in your system out printing you ask to print the first column of that row.

Comment: `wp` are your rows and in this row you're picking the first column's value (`wp[0]`).

Comment: ahhh okay so 
for(int[] wp : wps){
              System.out.println(wp[0]);
the first time around it is [0][0]
second time around it is [1][0]
and so on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have arrays as your elements. While looping inside wps, each array is read and its 0th element is being printed. That is why you are getting such result.

Comment: ahhh okay so 
for(int[] wp : wps){
              System.out.println(wp[0]);
the first time around it is [0][0]
second time around it is [1][0]
and so on?

Comment: Thanks a lot, I understand it now

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print them as a table, you should print them row by row, not column by column. Once in the new line, there is no way back.

```
for(int[] wp : wps){
    for (int i : wp) {
        System.out.println(i + " ");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, much appreciated